# Looking for a Command-line Portable ssh server (reverse connect)

Tags: windows, remote-access, command-line, ssh, portable

I have been searching recently for a command-line server for remote administration on Windows. I have also used ncat, which got the job done but unfortunately it is flagged by antiviruses. I needed a alternative. So, I came up with a idea of portable ssh server, which needs to fulfill following features:

1. Command line (like ncat)
2. Supports reverse connection for LAN machines
3. Portable